# Microsoft word how to link a text to a DYNAMIC figure

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2011

I'm writing a word document that contains many figures. I know example how to number the figures. My problem is that I don't know how to link the figure to a specific text. For example.

Let's say I want to write the following:

> Figure 3-3 shows you the chosen dress for 30% of under-24-years-old girls in Lisbon.

how can I link the word `Figure 3-3` to my actual figure?

I could add a **field** myself and link it to a figure, but let's say I added a figure before that figure, then the number of that figure will change and my text will point to another figure.

so basically guys i want to ask you how to link a text to a dynamic figure and text updated with the actual number of the figure.

I'm working on this word

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [cross-references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-update-a-cross-reference-aa35c606-34e8-4c64-b6eb-c6321d190645):

> A cross-reference refers to an item that appears in another location
>   in a document. For example, you can mention "Figure 1" in your
>   document and refer the reader to the figure's location elsewhere in
>   the document. By default, Word inserts a cross-reference as a
>   hyperlink that you can click to be taken directly to the
>   cross-referenced item. You can create cross-references to items such
>   as headings, footnotes, bookmarks, captions, and numbered paragraphs.
>   If you add or remove content that causes the referenced item to move,
>   you can update the cross-reference.

Normally in MS word cross-reference can be added via "Insert" menu. There are different options allowing you to insert the numbered-item, item text, page or paragraph number of the object you referencing.

Every time you want to refresh the cross-references you can use a combination of

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (*select all*)
- <kbd>F9</kbd> (*refresh*)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pick up your phrase (Figure 3-3) and make a right-click on it. In the list pick "Add a hyper link" and write needed link in the window. Press OK and violas - your link should be in the document!